# I can't clone repo on windows with powershell

Tags: windows, git, powershell, github

When I clone it keeps saying "Cloning into 'hack'..." but I can't find anything in C:\github and when i type cd project name I get the error message:

```
 Set-Location : Cannot find path 'C:\github\'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clone the project to the current folder,

cd into the folder with the name hack

```
# clone the project to the current directory
git clone <url>

# cd into the code folder
cd <project name>
```

The content is located in the current folder inside the cloned name.

[image]